# Which scenario is the best for service worker architecture?

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, web-services, microservices

We know about using service workers in modern web sites.

Consider a scenario back-end as node.js and SQL Server.

Data is loaded from central database to local customer web app (DB is about 700 MB) and maybe each days update about 2 MB.

Can this situation handle via Service Worker or Browser Cache?

Which is the best software architecture for load data one time from central DB and use in local customer browser and use for many times or update each day about maximum 2 MB.

Comment: you want to replicate the enitre 700Mb database on the client browser, pulling a delta of changes when t reconnects?

Comment: yes, I want to entire 700 mb data at first run push to client and after that using just minor update and sync with clients. @Ewan

Comment: You don't need an architecture for what amounts to a simple (albeit large) data transfer.  The load time is going to be dictated largely by the quality of your internet connection.

Comment: The main problem is service worker can be fine in such a way or we should use a local DB? @RobertHarvey

Comment: OP, I am not clear on why you believe a local database and a service worker are mutually exclusive, or even related in any way. One holds stuff, one does stuff. Very different.

Answer (score 1):

So a quick google shows that there are solutions out there such as PouchDB. but that 700Mb is probably going to be too big for most browsers.

https://pouchdb.com/faq.html

It sounds to me like you would be better served by a native application rather than a web app in your case.

This will give you many more options for handing the data sync 'offline'as it were and all you to handle the volume of data int he local database that you require.

Comment: what do you mean by "would be better served by a native application rather than a web app in your case."

Comment: I mean write an application that the user installs on their device, rather than a web page they visit on a browser

Comment: Is it possible to share code or documentation? another important tips that so user can download data from central database?

Comment: check out (and upvote!!) my other answers on the topic 
 https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340061/what-is-a-good-software-architecture-for-pos-with-offline-mode/340064#340064

Comment: In your answer there is a big gap. how you can handle first sync and transfer from server to client? and why service worker is not works?